# PrimeNG not updating model value for p-autoComplete

Tags: html, angular

```
<p-autoComplete [style]="{'width':'100%'}" name="searchSuggestions" 
[(ngModel)]="suggestion" (completeMethod)="searchSuggestions($event)" 
[suggestions]="searchSuggestionsResult" field="field"></p-autoComplete>
```

I am using `p-autoComplete`. On copy and paste text using mouse, model value (suggestion) coming as undefined. How to take pasted value from model?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you're pasting the text in, it's not registering as a "select" event because you're not actually using the autocompletion functionality The use case you're describing of copy and paste is more suited to:
   `<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="property"/>`

Comment: I need auto suggestions @David

Answer (score 0):

Copying and pasting of strings to p-autoComplete  works fine for me. I'm just gonna share my method hoping you find light in it.

Html:

```
<p-autoComplete [style]="{'width':'100%'}" name="searchSuggestions" 
        [(ngModel)]="suggestion" (completeMethod)="searchSuggestions(suggestion)" 
        [suggestions]="searchSuggestionsResult" field="field">
</p-autoComplete>
```

Notice that I passed the model to the completeMethod as a parameter. 
Oh and by the way I'm using typescript for Angular 2.

Ts:

```
searchSuggestions(suggestion) {
    this.searchSuggestionsResult = [];

    if(suggestion != "") {

        var list = this.searchSuggestionsResult.filter(function(el) {
            return (el) ? el.toLowerCase().startsWith(suggestion.toLowerCase()) : false;
        });

        list.sort((a,b) => a.toLowerCase().localCompare(b.toLowerCase());
        list.forEach(element => {
            this.searchSuggestionsResult.push(element);
        });
    } else {
        this.searchSuggestionsResult = [];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use onClear() method & set your model values = null

====HTML

```
(onClear)="clearValue()"
```

==ts

```
clearValue()
{
    this.searchSuggestionsResult = null;
}
```

This function will get called only when you are cleared all the values from auto-complete list.

Hope this will work!!